# multiple decending objects in c++

Tags: c++, class, object

I am new to working with C++ and object oriented programming in general. My question is how to go about linking multiple objects with multiple subclass objects each with multiple data variables to track?

Essentially I have the object type "reciever". Each "reciever" has specific variables to store comming in on a data stream. However, each "reciever" has 32 possible "channels". Each channel has more data variables to store.

Say I want the program to have a maxium of 100 recievers. What is the best way to structure this? I have been thinking this way:

```
    class BaseStation{
public:
    string baseID;
    int numberSat;
    FP64 timeUTC;
    INT16U week;
    FP64 GPStoUTCoffset;
    FP64 GLOtoUTCoffset;
    INT8S recieverTimeOffset;
    FP64 posX; //geocentric coordinates in meters
    FP64 posY;
    FP64 posZ;
    FP64 rmsX;  //expected root mean square error of coordinates
    FP64 rmsY;
    FP64 rmsZ;
 };

class Channels : public BaseStation
{
public:
    INT8U systemID;
    INT8U satID;
    INT8U GlonassNumber;
    INT8U SNR;         //signal to noise ratio
    FP64 carrierPhase; //cylces
    FP64 psuedoRange;  //milliseconds
    FP64 doppler;      //HZ cycles

    FP64 tropDelay; //meters
    FP64 ionoDelay; //meters
};
```

Then create objects like:

```
    Channels base[100];
Channels channel[100][32];
```

Other than just making sure that both the array pointer for base and channel are the same is there a way to tie 32 channels to a single base object?

Answer (score 0):

The receiver has a one-to-many relationship with channels.  If you know you'll always have 32 you can do something like this:

```
class Receiver {

    Channel channels[32];

    /* variables specific to a receiver */

    string baseID;
    int numberSat;
    FP64 timeUTC;
    INT16U week;
    FP64 GPStoUTCoffset;
    FP64 GLOtoUTCoffset;
    INT8S recieverTimeOffset;
    FP64 posX; //geocentric coordinates in meters
    FP64 posY;
    FP64 posZ;
    FP64 rmsX;  //expected root mean square error of coordinates
    FP64 rmsY;
    FP64 rmsZ;

};
```

That's the simplest variation.  It's likely superior to use an array of pointers (setting channels to NULL if they're not present/in use).  Alternately you could look into using `STL::vector`.

```
class Channel {

    /* variables specific a single channel */

    INT8U systemID;
    INT8U satID;
    INT8U GlonassNumber;
    INT8U SNR;         //signal to noise ratio
    FP64 carrierPhase; //cylces
    FP64 psuedoRange;  //milliseconds
    FP64 doppler;      //HZ cycles

    FP64 tropDelay; //meters
    FP64 ionoDelay; //meters

};
```

Then in your top level module, create an array of 100 Receivers:

```
Receiver allReceivers[100];
```

Again, if you won't always have exactly 100 there are much better ways to store this as you would with channels in the receiver above.  You could also encapsulate the receivers into a top-level class and manage array of receivers in there.

Also watch out for:

```
Channels channel[100][32];
```

Here, you're declaring a 2 dimensional array of channels.  This could work, but using encapsulating the set of channels in the receiver (to model the relationship) is better OOP.

Good luck!